Are all scratch orgs created with an org shape trial orgs?
I recently decided to try out the org shape feature and created a shape from a client's production instance. Then, when creating a scratch org with the sourceOrg in the definition file pointing to that client's production (which is also the Dev Hub), I got the scratch org created, but there's a catch: the org has a trial banner at the top:

This happened when creating a scratch org with the default number of days to live and then specifying 30 days:

Is this normal for scratch orgs created with the Org Shapes feature?

As per this post's reply, by Rohit Mehta, from Salesforce:

The banner is an extension of the scratch org being short-lived and should not affect functionality. We have plans to fix it so that you have the same experience as other scratch orgs.

So it affects only the aesthetic, but feature-wise this shouldn't impact development or other usage of the scratch org.
Bear in mind that this post is from Mar 28, 2019.
